# Disable Edit and delete options in a list

Tags: permissions, editing-menu

I do have a custom list and this is used for history tracking - only add is allowed. How do I disable "Edit" and "Delete" menus both from the ribbon and on the context menu only for this specific list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are security trimmed so people with only Add permissions won't see them, owners and administrators will.  Since Add only isn't a default permission set, I'm assuming you created a cutom permission and applied it to the users via creating a broken permissions.  They will not see those options, well, they'll be displayed, but they'll be greyed out.